# segmentation fault pushing back to vector in shared memory

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, shared-memory

I working on a program that simulates travel agents booking flights in parallel. It spins up a process for each agent and works against an array of `Plane` objects held in shared memory.

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to push a row of seats back to the plane. The method to parse the input file calls a `SetSeats()` method on `Plane` objects. Each `Plane` contains a `vector<map<char, Seat>>` (each index of the vector is a row, each key of each map is the letter of a seat on that row).  When I call `SetSeats()` it goes fine through adding seats to the first map, i.e. the first row of seats. It throws the segfault when I try to push the map back to the seats vector.

I saw something online about pushing back custom classes to vectors needing deconstructors, so I added them to Seat.h and Plane.h.

Code for the main program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#incluce <string>
#include <fstream>

#include "Seat.h"
#include "Plane.h"

void ParseInputFile(ifstream &inFS, int numPlanes, int &numAgents);
int shmid;
int *timer;
int numPlanes, numAgents;
struct sembuf *ops;
Plane *sharedPlanes;
map<string, Plane*> planes;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ifstream inFS;
  // code to get an input file from command line arguments and get number of planes from it

  // set up shared memory segment
  long key = XXX; // just a long integer
  int nbytes = 1024;
  shmid = shmget((key_t)key, nbytes, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
  if (shmid == -1)
  {
    printf("Error in shared memory region setup.\n");
    perror("REASON");

    exit(2);
  }

  // initialize global variables
  sharedPlanes = new Plane[numPlanes];
  timer = new int;
  ops = new sembuf[1];

  // attached shared pointers to shared memory segment
  sharedPlanes = (Plane*)shmat(shmid, (Plane*)0, 0);
  timer = (int*)shmat(shmid, (int*)0, 0);
  *timer = 0;

  inFS.open(inputFile);

  ParseInputFile(inFS, numPlanes, numAgents); // breaks in here
 
  // the rest of main()
}

void ParseInputFile(ifstream &inFS, int numPlanes, int &numAgents)
{
  string line = "";

    bool foundNumberOfPlanes = false;
    bool foundPlanes = false;
    bool foundNumberOfAgents = false;
    bool lookingForAgent = false;
    bool foundAgent = false;
    
    int planeNo = 0;
    int agentNo = 0;
    int opNo = 0;

    map<string, Operation> ops;
    vector<Request> agentRequests;

    while (getline(inFS, line))
    {
        if (!CommonMethods::IsWhitespace(line))
        {
            // code to read first line

            if (foundNumberOfPlanes && !foundPlanes)
            {
                // parse a line from the input file to get details about the plane

                Plane *plane = &sharedPlanes[planeNo];

                unsigned int rows = xxx; // set based on the plane details
                unsigned int seatsPerRow = xxx; set based on the plane details

                plane->SetSeats(rows, seatsPerRow); // this is the method where I get the seg fault

                // finish defining the plane

                continue;

                // the rest of the method
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for Plane.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

#include "Seat.h"
#include "Exceptions.h"
#include "ReservationStatus.h"
#include "CommonMethods.h"

using namespace std;

class Plane
{
    private:        
        vector<map<char, Seat>> seats;
        unsigned int numberOfRows, numberOfSeatsPerRow;
    public:
        Plane(unsigned int numberOfRows, unsigned int numberOfSeatsPerRow);
        Plane() {}
        void SetSeats(unsigned int numberOfRows, unsigned int numberOfSeatsPerRow);
};

void Plane::SetSeats(unsigned int numberOfRows, unsigned int numberOfSeatsPerRow)
{
    //cout << "Clearing old seats" << endl;
    if (!seats.empty())
    {
        //cout << "Seats not empty" << endl;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)seats.size(); i++)
        {
            //cout << "checking row " << i << endl;

            if (!seats.at(i).empty())
            {
                //cout << "Row " << i << " not empty" << endl;

                seats.at(i).clear();
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Rows: " << numberOfRows << ", Seats: " << numberOfSeatsPerRow << endl;

    this->numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
    this->numberOfSeatsPerRow = numberOfSeatsPerRow;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        map<char, Seat> row;

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->numberOfSeatsPerRow; j++)
        {
            Seat seat;
            seat.RowNumber = i + 1;
            seat.SeatLetter = j + 'A';

            //cout << "Inserting seat " << seat.RowNumber << seat.SeatLetter << endl;

            row.insert(pair<char, Seat>(seat.SeatLetter, seat));
        }

        if (!row.empty())
        {
            cout << "inserting row " << (i + 1) << endl;
            seats.push_back(row);
        }
    }
}

void Plane::ProcessWaitAny(int t)
{
    while (!WaitingList.empty())
    {
        bool booked = false;
        string pass = WaitingList.front();
        WaitingList.pop();

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < numberOfRows; j++)
        {
            if (booked)
                break;

            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < numberOfSeatsPerRow; k++)
            {
                Seat *s = &seats.at(j)[k + 'A'];

                if (!s->IsBooked)
                {
                    Reserve(s, pass);
                    booked = true;

                    string seatNo = to_string(j);
                    seatNo += (k + 'A');

                    cout << "Passenger " << pass << " booked into seat " << seatNo << " at time " << t << endl;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!booked)
            return;
    }
}
```

Code for Seat.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct Seat
{
    string Passenger = "";
    bool IsBooked = false;
    unsigned int RowNumber;
    char SeatLetter;
    queue<string> WaitingList;
};
```

Comment: cannot compile since some of your headers needed by Plane.h are missing

Comment: It compiles. I only included here what I thought was relevant since this was already a long post.

Comment: @dfoakley No, your example does **not** compile. Your original code might, but not what you posted in this question. Get rid of the not-needed `#include` lines and either declare `Plane::WaitingList` or remove the (pointless) clearing of it in `~Plane()`.

Comment: Is shared memory necessary for this example? If you drop that part of the code and rely on traditional memory management, does the segmentation fault disappear?

Comment: Updated post to include all of Plane.h

The the part included in "// the rest of main()" spins up several child processes via fork() and they all need to access the planes. Using shared memory is a requirement of the assignment. I haven't tried removing it.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but the `Plane` destructor is unnecessary. One of the points of using `vector`, `queue`, `map` etc is that these objects can clean up themselves. Ditto `Seat`.

Comment: *"I saw something online about pushing back custom classes to vectors needing deconstructors, so I added them to Seat.h and Plane.h."* -- Either what you read was wrong or you misunderstood what you read. The destructors you wrote for `Seat` and `Plane` do nothing more than what the compiler-provided destructor would do, and your versions are potentially less efficient.

Comment: *"Updated post to include all of Plane.h"* -- please don't. See [mre].

Comment: *"Using shared memory is a requirement of the assignment."* -- that's not relevant. We are not grading your assignment. Your example code should include just enough code to reproduce the problem. *"I haven't tried removing it."* -- please do try. Removing unnecessary noise makes it easier (for both us *and you*) to see the cause of a problem.

Comment: That did get rid of the segfault. But, like I said, I can't not do it.

Comment: @dfoakley That is important information. We can focus on your use of the shared memory API. Please look at the other parts of your code to see what you can remove. Which operation triggers the crash, and which are required to set up the crash? Everything else can be trimmed off the example.

Comment: Trimmed down my code samples.

It crashes when I try to push the map<char, Seat> row back to the vector.

Comment: Also, don't know if it's useful, but I'm running this on an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS server, compiled using g++ -std=c++11

Answer (score 0):

I have made a minimum working example of your problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <iostream>

class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {};
    std::vector<int> vec;
};

int main() {
  int shmid;
  Bar* a = new Bar();
  a->vec.push_back(1);
  // set up shared memory segment
  long key = 0x123455; // just a long integer
  int nbytes = 1024;
  shmid = shmget((key_t)key, nbytes, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
  if (shmid == -1)
  {
    printf("Error in shared memory region setup.\n");
    perror("REASON");

    exit(2);
  }
  a = (Bar*)shmat(shmid, (Bar*)0, 0);

  a->vec.push_back(2);
}
```

The problem is your wrong usage of `shmat`. The pointer `sharedPlane` just points to some unitialized shared memory. You have to make sure that the address provided by `key` is 'right'. To do this, do the following:

1. Your other process, call `Plane * other_process_sharedPlane = new Plane();`. Remove the line `sharedPlanes = new Plane[numPlanes];` from your main programm.
2. In your main process, set `key` to the value of `other_process_sharedPlane`
3. Then you can call shmget and shmadd